# Strange monadic behaviour

Tags: haskell

I tried to write a program which takes filepaths as (command line) arguments and returns the first line of each file

```
main = getArgs >>= ( mapM_ ( \file -> ( openFile file ReadMode >>= ( (\handle -> hGetLine handle >>= print)  >> hClose )  ) ) )
```

I know that this doesn't look very beautiful but I am just a beginner in Haskell. I did also avoid the do notation on purpose because I just don't feel very comfortable with her (yet).

So the Code above compiles and returns an error for invalid file paths, and nothing (i.e. especially not the first line of a file) for valid paths.

I must confess that I have pretty much no idea what I did wrong, but I made the following observation:
If I add the following to check which parts still get executed

```
main = getArgs >>= ( mapM_ ( \file -> ( openFile file ReadMode >>= ( (\handle -> hGetLine handle >>= print) >> (const $ putStr "Hello1")  >> hClose >> (const $ putStr "Hello2") )  ) ) )
```

the program prints only the second "Hello", this reminded me of the type signature of (>>):

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

so taking into perspective that only something of the type of the second argument gets returned, maybe the first argument is just ignored?
But the first argument against this theory is that such a function would not seem to be very useful (at least not in the context of the IO Monad), and the second is that the program

```
main = (putStr "Hello" >> putStr "World" >> putStr "!")
```

returns 'HelloWorld!' as expected. Hence I must be completely on the wrong track, which is why I came here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `>>` only returns the result of the right one but it'll execute *both* **effects** - you should be good there - can you add an example on how you call your program and what the error is exactly? Maybe the files are indeed not there or found?

Comment: btw: you should really try and translate this into `do` - it should be straight forward (should look like what you expect in an imperative language) - it's hard to parse here (for me) as it's all in a line with lot's of `(`,,`)` and the scrollbar ;)

Comment: @Carsten 'an example on how you call your program and what the error is exactly': "./Main file.txt" returns "", "./Main file_notExistent.txt" returns "Main: file_notExistent.txt: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)". So the problem is not encaptured in a error message, but is rather the lack of any message. Regarding the do notation: My problem is that I always have to convert to notation back to explicit notation before I can understand it. Hard logic first and nice notation later, at least that is the way I learn best.

Comment: as I wrote bellow your issue is really that you did not put the `hClose` in the right place - this way the `>>` was for the `(->)` Monad not the `IO` - so it did indeed pass the `handle` to both the `hGetLine handle >>= print` and `hClose` but `>>` ignored the first resulting `IO` result and only returned the `hClose` one - so here the effect was passing the `handle` and the result was only closing the file - yes it's subtle and not obvious as you seldom see/think about the *reader-monad* instance (the Monad Instance for `(->) handle` here )

Comment: I'll agree that this is probably really puzzling to new (and even seasoned) Haskellers why this does not result in an type-error here and actually does something at runtime ... the `->` instances for functor, monad, etc. are nice but maybe not really beginner-friendly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you main error is that you messed up with the handle:

```hs
main = getArgs >>= (mapM_ (\file -> (openFile file ReadMode >>= (\handle -> (hGetLine handle >>= print)  >> hClose handle)  ) ) )
```

this way you did it `>>` was for the (`-> handle`) Monad (it's a reader monad - see there is an `Monad` instance for `(->) c` for constant `c`) not the `IO`!

So it did indeed pass the handle to both `hGetLine handle >>= print` and `hClose` but `>>` ignored the first *resulting* **IO action** and returned the `hClose` one as the result to `>>`

Here the **effect** was passing the handle!

So yes in the end the only executed IO-effect was closing the file!

It's subtle and not obvious as you seldom see/think about the reader-monad instance like this.

---

here is this with `do` notation

```hs
main = do
  args <- getArgs 
  mapM_ (\file -> do
    handle <- openFile file ReadMode
    line <- hGetLine handle
    print line
    hClose handle) args
```

and I'd suggest switching to `forM_` (from `Control.Monad`) for the args parameter:

```hs
main = do
  args <- getArgs 
  forM_ args (\file -> do
    handle <- openFile file ReadMode
    line <- hGetLine handle
    print line
    hClose handle)
```

now you should make sure you close the handle - you can use `bracket` from `Control.Exception` for this:

```hs
main = do
  args <- getArgs 
  forM_ args (\file -> do
    bracket
      (openFile file ReadMode)
      hClose
      (\h -> do
        line <- hGetLine h
        print line
      )
    )
```

or (as this is very common) just `withFile` from `System.IO` which does the opening/closing for you:

```hs
main = do
  args <- getArgs 
  forM_ args (\file -> do
    withFile file ReadMode
      (\h -> do
        line <- hGetLine h
        print line
      )
    )
```

finally you don't really have to use all the *handle*  stuff you can use the (*lazy*) `readFile` instead and be a bit safer with empty files too:

```hs
main = do
  args <- getArgs 
  forM_ args (\file -> do
    content <- readFile file
    let ls = lines content
    case ls of
      [] -> putStrLn "no line in file"
      (firstLine:_) -> putStrLn firstLine
    )
```